# How to solve this geometry problem which involves triangles and triangulation

Tags: geometry, triangulation

I need to solve this trig problem. Can you please help me?

Based on this image:
[image]

I need to calculate $PO$ based on the values of $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $AB$ ( Assume that I know the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ angles and length of $AB$). $O$ is the middle of $AB$.

Can this problem be solved?

Any clue on solving this problem is very appreciating!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We make use of the [Length of a Median](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml) formula relating the length of $PO$ with the lengths of the sides of the triangle. It is as follows
$$(PA)^2+(PB)^2=2(PO)^2+\frac{(AB)^2}{2}$$

But the lengths $PA, PB$ are not given, so we need to calculate them.

To do so, we apply the law of sines, relating the lengths of the sides of the triangle $APB$ to the sines of its angles.

Let $\gamma$ be the internal angle of $APB$ on $P$. We have
$$\frac{\sin \beta}{PA}=\frac{sin (\pi- \alpha)}{PB}=\frac{\sin \gamma}{AB}$$

Thus we have all the information needed to find $PO$.

Comment: where the first formula comes? Any reference to its proof? any name for the formula?

Comment: @mans I know it as the first middle-length theorem but I am not sure if this is how it is named in English bibliography. It's source is Euclidean Geometry. If you wish I will provide it's proof later on (got to go now! :-)).

Comment: Thanks, I looked for it in internet and could not find any information. In which language do you call it middle-length theorem?

Comment: In the graph that I sketched, I placed P above the A and B, what would be the case if: 1- P be between A and B, 2_ P be below of B? Is there any change in the formula?

Comment: Well, instead of writing down the proof, I will provide a link. The name of the formula in English turns out to be-unsurprisingly- "Length of a Median". This is the simplest proof I know of- http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/LengthOfMedian.shtml (You can also make use of the Generalized Pythagorean Theorem and a couple of Lemmas but this is very direct and intuitive.) There is no change in the formula when you consider other placements of BB, it holds in general. Hope it helped!